# Vuejs how to use Vue-slick in childs component?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, components

i need to use more than one slider in my site, i done it by import Vueslick to child component one by one, but i want to import only one Slick library, this is my idea:

```
<pre><code>
<template>
  <div>
   <slider :slickOptionsSlider='slickOptionsSlider'></slider>
   <blogsuckhoe :slickOptionsBlogsuckhoe='slickOptionsBlogsuckhoe' ></blogsuckhoe>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  data() {
    //import slick và child component
    return {
      slickOptionsSlider: {
        autoplay:true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots:false,
        arrows:false,
      },
      slickOptionsBlogsuckhoe: {
        autoplay:true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots:false,
        arrows:false,
      },
    };
  }
</script>
</code></pre>
```

sure, it is not working. Can you help me ? Thank you . Im sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register it as a global component.

**app.js**

```php
Vue.component('vue-slick',require('vue-slick').default);
```

Then use it anywhere inside your root element, within a component or directly in a blade template.

**SomeComponent.Vue**

```html
<vue-slick :options='options'></vue-slick>
```

**some.blade.php**

```html
<vue-slick :options='@json($options)'></vue-slick>
```

Comment: but i dont need it in other sites . Im using Vue router, can i require it  in Parent component?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html  Could you create a separate file (e.g., yoursite.js) where you put site-specific resources, then load the compiled script only on that site?